# Pylint error W0232: class has no __init__ method

Tags: python, class, pylint

I have the following error with pylint:

```
Pylint error W0232: class has no __init__ method
```

I understand what it means. I have to create the `__init__` method.
The problem is that this class is inherited from parent class. I know that I'm able to create the `__init__` method and just use `super(myclass, self).__init__()` but is it really necessary? I have nothing to add to `__init__`. I want to know if it is a better practice to create `__init__` method in any class.

Comment: Then configure pylint to ignore this error class.

Comment: but then it might be wrong practice

Comment: Im new to python. I love my code to be written within the best practice.

Comment: [The documentation for W0232](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0232) suggests that this message should only appear when neither the class *nor its parent classes* have an `__init__` method.  This is either because Pylint cannot find your parent class (in which case you need to re-configure how you are calling it, so that it can properly lint your code) or else you have discovered a bug in Pylint.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes I do. He cannot detect a class written not by me. It is the class `sockjsConnection`

Comment: You should not write a dumb __init__ method just because pylint tells you it's missing. If you feel like a __init__ method isn't necessary, disable the message locally.

Comment: the class have the on_open method. I want to use it to declare a varable like `self.authenticated = false`
Should i create an __init__ method for that? and set `self.authenticated = None` or something like that? Or is it ok to declare it in `on_open`

Answer (score 2):

As @Sean pointed out, `pylint` [*should not*](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:w0232) complain if `__init__()` is defined in a parent class. Сhances are `pylint` cannot find that class. Make sure the module defining it is actually loaded when you [invoke](http://docs.pylint.org/run.html) `pylint` (e.g. run it on the containing package).